# Config File Management plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am very new to Jenkins.I went through this webpage (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin#ConfigFileProviderPlugin-MavenServerCredentials%28since2.7%29) and installed Config file management plugin in jenkins. I am able to create global Maven settings.xml and I am also able to attach it from the project configuration page so that the project can use the settings.xml while compiling. I am also able to add some credentials to the config file as well.
My question is: what is the use of adding credentials to the settings.xml file.

Please pardon,if my question sounds too silly. Please help me out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here credentials are needed to perform some different tasks. e.g.

- To deploy project to remote server needs username/password (of remote   server's)
- To clone a private repo (from [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)/[GitHub](https://github.com/)) for building Jenkins job needs username/password.

Also can use 'SSH username with private key'.